# PHP Database Class Error

Tags: php, mysqli

Below are the files that im using (trying) to pull information from a DB but it gives me an error.

Config file:

```
define("DBHOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DBUSER", "root");
define("DBPASS", "root");
define("DBNAME", "test");
define("DBPORT", "3306");
```

DB Class:

```
class Database{

    public function __contruct(){
        $con = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME, DBPORT);

        if (!$con){
            die("Error connecting to database");
        }
        else{
            $this->con = $con;
        }
    }

    function SimpleQuery(){
        $query="SELECT * FROM accounts";
        $array = $this->con->query($query);
        while ($fields = $array->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $values[] = $fields;
        }
        return $values;
    }
}
```

Index file:

```
require ("config.php");
require ("database.php");

$db = new Database();

echo $rows = $db->SimpleQuery();
```

Gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in database.php
```

Comment: I think you should declare $con inside you class. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: non of those things work :(

Comment: @Phentom it's a typo. You have `__contruct` instead of `__construct`. Plus, you should check for connection errors using `$this->con->connect_errors` (gives more details as to why the connection failed).

Comment: damm, always this little mistakes! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 semi colons in the con = statement of the DB class

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**DB Class:**

```
class Database{

    public function __construct(){
                        // ^ problem here
        $con = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME, DBPORT);

        if (!$con){
            die("Error connecting to database");
        }
        else{
            $this->con = $con;
        }
    }

    function SimpleQuery(){
        $query="SELECT * FROM accounts";
        $array = $this->con->query($query);
        while ($fields = $array->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $values[] = $fields;
        }
        return $values;
    }
}
```

**index file:**

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
include("submit.php");

$db = new Database();
 $rows = $db->SimpleQuery();
 print_r($rows);
```